# Computer can't access shared folder even though they're showing up in explorer

Tags: windows, windows-10, networking, wireless-networking

Computer setup is this.
Ws1
Ws2
Ws3
Named PC are all wired directly into the switch.

Ws4 is connected to an access point also plugged into the switch. It has a TP Link external wifi dongle

Network flow is modem-pfsense router-netgear switch-netgear AP.

I need to connect WS4 to the named PC for shared folders.

The computers show up in explorer, but clicking on them to open it brings up an error that says the problem has to be not on ws4 but on every other computer in the network.

All are running Windows 10 Pro, in the same workgroup. Firewalls are disabled at the moment.

Comment: Is File and Print enabled on all machines?  Are the shared folders named and shared to the appropriate machines in the network?  I ensure this and can map any folder.

Comment: What are the IP addresses of the router and all 4 computers.

Comment: Are your wireless devices set up with private (not public) connections?

Comment: @John everything is setup with private connections. I've set up the shared folders, the problem is that this one computer (ws4) can't access any folders on the network. All of the others are sharing the way they're supposed to.

Comment: Maybe try resetting TCP/IP on that machine to see if it works.

Answer (score 1):

to go step by step:

1. first, ping ip addresses of ws1, ws2, ws3 from ws4.
2. if you get answer to ping, try to access hidden folders on one of the ws* . try this from start->run : \ws1\c$ . it sould ask a username and password. see if you can see access the folder after providing username and password.
3. if you can access the c$ on ws* workstations, it means that you are connect to network and you should be able to access to shared folders, if they are shared properly. so in this case problem should be with permissions of your shared folders.
   go check permissions of shared folders you want to access.